# How to stop PagedListAdapter initial load animation?

Tags: android

I am working on implementing the PagedList and ListAdapter for my recyclerviews in my app where applicable. I am doing this by loading a livedata from my Dao and then giving it to the adapter.

The issue that I have run into is that when the list first loads, the adapter shows an insert animation for every item in the list, which creates a very undesirable effect and breaks animations.

How do I make it so the recyclerview does not show these animations on the initial creation?

Comment: Do you have solved?

Comment: It stopped happening on it's own using the latest AndroidX

Comment: I use it but the animation will performed always